# Getting the sum from receipt with ML-Kit

Tags: android, ocr, firebase-mlkit, google-mlkit

For my project the user takes a picture of a receipt and it returns the date of purchase,the sum and the name of the shop where you made your purchase.
My idea was that I will take the largest or second largest Int that ML-Kit returns, as that is usually the sum.
But the way the date is printed in german is 01.01.2021, which is also interpreted as an int and often times the highest number.

The layout of the sum on the receipt looks like this (the "---" is blank space)

SUMME-------------------EUR-----9,58

This causes ML-Kit to recognize each String as a single block.

Is there a way to simply extract the sum? Or maybe a better free OCR that already specifies in receipts?

Comment: were you able to find a solution to get the amount from MLKit? I'm currently looking for that as well using MLKit

Answer (score 0):

If your volume is low, we at Asprise offer a [free Receipt OCR API](https://asprise.com/receipt-ocr-data-capture-api/extract-text-reader-scanner-index.html) - no registration required. It works for receipts from many countries including Germany.

[image: Asprise receipt OCR for Germany receipts]